# Multinomial distribution: bounding sum of coordinates' deviations from mean

Tags: probability-theory, distribution-tails, concentration-of-measure

Okay, given a multinomial random vector 
$$X=\text{Multinom}(n,\;p_{1},\;\dots,\;p_{k}),$$
so that
$$X=(X_{1},\;\dots,\;X_{k})\;\;\;\text{with} \;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_{i}=n,$$
I'm looking for a bound on
$$\textbf{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|X_{i}-np_{i}| \geq \lambda\sqrt{n}).$$

I know that such an inequality exists (in some obscure textbook) but I'm having trouble finding it. (I had the specific document downloaded, but my computer crashed and I can't find it again.) If anybody knows where I could find such a result, I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: A simple proof of the Bretagnolle-Huber-Carol inequality appears in: Yuto Ushioda, Masato Tanaka, Tomomi Matsui (2022). "Monte Carlo Methods for the Shapley–Shubik Power Index". Games. 13 (3): 44. doi:10.3390/g13030044.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. We have

$$\textbf{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|X_{i}-n p_{i}| \geq 2 \lambda \sqrt{n}) \leq 2^{k}\exp(-2\lambda^{2})$$

for any real $\lambda$. Apparently this is known as the Bretagnolle-Huber-Carol inequality. I'm getting it from the Appendix of "Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes" by van der Vaart and Wellner. My original reference was this post from mathoverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14560/statistical-approach-to-multinomial-distribution